# google maps, is there any possible way to store markers?

Tags: android, onclick, sharedpreferences, google-maps-markers

Hi I have created some simple code where when I click on the map a marker is added but the problem is that if I rerun the application the markers that I added they disappear.Is there any possible way to somehow make them visible even if I rerun the application ? Thanks.
Code for markers onmapclick:

```
    gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));

        }

    });
```

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/ check this blog. There you'll find tutorials for what you need exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user click on the map... get the latitude and longitude of the location and save the values in a database table. whenever map load, you should select marker locations and add them to the map

Answer (score 0):

Like Dehan Wijesekara said, you can save values in a database but if you want keep it simpler you can use shared preferences.

Comment: hey can u show me an example of how can i add the marker in shared preferences ? thanks.